# How do I use functions as variables?

Tags: c#, javascript

So I'm used to working with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), and being able to simply do

```
dog={};
dog.name="Rex";
dog.examine=function(){console.log("This is a dog. Its name is "+this.name+".");}
cat={};
cat.name="Phil Collins";
cat.examine=function(){console.log("This is a cat. Its name is "+this.name+".");}

dog.examine();
cat.examine();
```

This would return, of course : *`This is a dog. Its name is Rex.`* and *`This is a cat. Its name is Phil Collins.`*

I've started learning [xna](/questions/tagged/xna), and I'm very confused by this whole `lambda`/`delegate`/`action` system. I'm not sure what syntax to use, the compiler gets angry when I try to make a function with no input or output variables, and I'm having trouble keeping the proper scope for *`this`*. Could someone please help me find out how I'd port the above code into [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)?

Comment: Take a c# book and learn?

Comment: Can you post the C# code you have?  Also, C# is a compiled, strongly typed language with strict rules (essentially the complete oposite of JavaScript).  You would do well to do some more basic things and get familiar with the language as the syntax for declaring variables properties (which is what you want) and functions are very different from JS.

Comment: I echo @xDaevax: we can't tell you why the compiler doesn't like your C# code unless you include that code in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this a Community Wiki because this question is really too broad, C# and JavaScript are very different things and answer can't be complete. I'll just sketch a *direction* but the way to go is to learn C# and differences will be clear. That's the reason I'll try to first write something *similar* to JavaScript program you posted and then, step by step, to change it to be more C# style.

Let me also say that if you extensively want to use dynamic typing in C# (or JavaScript programming style) then (probably)...you picked wrong language.

### Step 1

Something somehow close to what you write can be written in C# like this (let me use this example to highlight differences, you really have to buy a good C# book and start from there):

```
dynamic dog = new ExpandoObject();
dog.Name = "Pluto";
dog.Hello = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("This is a dog named {0}", dog.Name));
dog.Hello();
```

1. First of all you see that in C# a variable must be typed, in this case with `dynamic` we bypass static typing and we may even change content later (but this is another story). `ExpandoObject` is a *special* object that can be expanded adding properties, it's not *normal* C# behavior where almost everything about types is checked at compile-times (don't think about casts, now).
2. Second line is pretty similar, nothing new (for you) here but pretty *strange* if you're a *traditional* C# programmer.
3. Finally the interesting part: we add a property that is a delegate (using a lambda) but here there is a big difference (you also noted by yourself): `this` has a different meaning in C# and within a method `this` is the instance of the object where method is declared (OK it's declared in the class but you know what I mean). Let's watch this: `dog.Name`, we *captured* `dog` variable inside our anonymous method (as you would do in JavaScript).

### Step 2

It's just a starting point because design and philosophy is completely different, same thing in C# should be done with an `Animal` base class and `Dog` + `Cat` derived classes but you'll learn this by yourself. Let me do just one more simple step in that direction:

```
var typedDog = new {
    Name = "Pluto",
    Hello = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("This is a dog named {0}", Name))
};
typedDog.Hello();
```

Maybe you don't see such big difference but this code is strongly typed! What does it means? We declared an anonymous class with two properties and one of them is a delegate, we still can't use `this` and in C# (unlike Java) we can't declare methods in anonymous types but now compiler knows (then it's compile-time) what things are. For example:

```
dog.Name = 2; // Valid, now Name is an integer
dog.Hello = 2; // Valid, also Hello is an integer
dog.Hello(); // This will fail at run-time because Hello now isn't a delegate
```

Is it bad, right? With our new typed object this isn't possible:

```
typedDog.Name = 2; // Compile-time error, Name is a string
typedDog.Hello = 2; // Compile-time error, Hello must be an Action delegate
```

Of course we can assign a new anonymous delegate to replace old one (but type must match):

```
typedDog.Hello = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("This is a typed dog named {0}", typedDog.Name));
```

### Step 3

This has been extensively described in other answers so I won't repeat, just to sketch things:

```
class Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void Hello();
}

class Dog : Animal {
    public override void Hello() {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a dog named {0}", this.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that now you finally have `this` pointer and it does what you expect. It's used like this:

```
var dog = new Dog { Name = "Pluto" };
dog.Hello();
```

Note that in JavaScript you can even write this:

```
var anInteger = 2;
anInteger.PrintSomething();
```

That's not allowed in C# because at compile-time (unless you use `dynamic` variables) it needs to know if `PrintSomething()` is a method and how to call it. Same thing can be also done like this (using interfaces):

```
class IPolite {
    void Hello();
}

class Dog : IPolite {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Hello() {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a dog named {0}", this.Name);
    }
}
```

Now you can even have a completely different object:

```
class Car : IPolite {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Hello() {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a car, name is {0}", this.Name);
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
IPolite thing = new Dog { Name = "Pluto" };
thing.Hello();

thing = new Car { Name = "Ferrari F50" };
thing.Hello();
```

Please note we're reusing same `thing` variable. Many other things to see and to do...

Comment: +1 This approach with the appropriate warnings is very close to the original javascript.

Comment: @itsme86 yes, I wouldn't recommend this style for C# programs, I just wanted to show it's possible to mimic such style in C# (I saw other answers already gave the C# way for this).

Answer (score 2):

In general C# and other strongly-typed languages are VASTLY different from script / run-time languages like JS.  C# is a compiled language and this "strongly-typed" nature is ensured by the compiler. This is true for many type-safe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) languages.

Generally speaking a class structure in C# would look like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    //Fields or instance variables are typically hidden from the outside world (consuming code).  This is controlled by the 'access-modifier' in this case, private.
    private string _name;

    //Constructor is called when you use the 'new' keyword to instantiate an instance of a type that derives from Animal (Animal cannot be instantiated directly because it is abstract).
    protected Animal() {
        //Avoids null references unless someone overrides the property setter, for this example, it's safe enough
        _name = string.Empty;
    }

    //This is syntax for declaring a property
    //properties are publicly accessible pieces of data that control access to a basic
    // field (variable).
    // It allows you to apply logic to the field it wraps.
    // In this example, the field cannot be set to a null or empty string (except by the constructor, which bypasses the property.
    public virtual string Name {
        get { 
            return _name;
        } set {
            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
    } // end property Name

    //This is a method that must be overridden by any derived type that is not abstract and may (or may not) be overridden by a derived type that is abstract.
    public abstract void Examine();
}

public class Cat : Animal {
    public Cat : base() {}
    public override void Examine() {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("This is a cat.  It's name is ", this.Name, "."));
    }
}

public Class Dog : Animal {
    public Dog() : base() {}
    public override void Examine() {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("This is a dog.  It's name is ", this.Name, "."));
    }
}

//In some runnable code elsewhere like a console application:

Animal cat = new Cat() {Name = "Mittens"};
Animal dog = new Dog() {Name = "Fido"};
cat.Examine();
dog.Examine();
```

- For more information about access modifies, see here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Dunno if you know, but you can do `public string Name { get; private set }` (probably better to use `protected` though?)

Comment: That is true, but what if I wanted to name my dog Fido? :)

Comment: @xDaevax Right now your animals don't have any name at all. _name will just remain null.

Comment: @xDaevax `abstract` methods just must be overridden by a derived class. That derived class doesn't necessarily have to be non-abstract.

Comment: @itsme86 That's true there are many ways to skin this cat...  I have tweaked my answer to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance to accomplish it:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void Examine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a {0}. Its name is {1}.", this.GetType(), Name);
    }
}

public void Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name) : base(name) { }
}

public void Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name) : base(name) { }
}
```

Then you can create instances of these derived types:

```
static class Main(string[] args)
{
    Dog rex = new Dog("rex");
    Cat phil = new Cat("Phil Collins");

    rex.Examine();
    phil.Examine();
}
```

Comment: Heh, nice timing. I like your use of `GetType` over my `Type` property. +1

Comment: Yeah, very similar approaches. I actually had a `Type` property originally.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example. I'd strongly suggest picking up a book or checking out a tutorial because this stuff will be covered pretty early on.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected Animal(string type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public virtual string Examine()
    {
        return string.Format("This is a {0}. Its name is {1}.", Type, Name);
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog() : base("Dog")
    {
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat() : base("Cat")
    {
    }
}

var dog = new Dog { Name = "Rex" };
var cat = new Cat { Name = "Phil Collins" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the so-called anonymous functions or you could make this examine function of yours to be a property of type Action. For e.g., you could write:

Animal.cs:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Action Examine { get; set;}
}
```

Dog.cs:

```
public class Dog : Animal
{

}
```

Cat.cs:

```
public class Cat : Animal
{

}
```

And then, somewhere where you could use this, you can say:

```
Dog dog = new Dog { Name = "Rex" };
dog.Examine = delegate
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a dog. Its name is {0}.", dog.Name);
};

Cat cat = new Cat { Name = "Phil Collins" };
cat.Examine = delegate
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a cat. Its name is {0}.", cat.Name);
};

dog.Examine();
cat.Examine();
```

Bear in mind that instead of using 'this', you're using a reference to the previously instantiated class which extends Animal (Dog or Cat).

There's also the other option... Combining ExpandoObject class and a dynamic keyword:

```
dynamic dog = new ExpandoObject();
dog.Name = "Rex";

Action examineDog = delegate {
    Console.WriteLine("This is a dog. Its name is {0}.", dog.Name);
};

dog.Examine = examineDog;

dynamic cat = new ExpandoObject();
cat.Name = "Phil Collins";

Action examineCat = delegate
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a cat. Its name is {0}.", cat.Name);
};

cat.Examine = examineCat;

dog.Examine();
cat.Examine();
```